# Accessing the top bar of UIImagePickerController Camera view

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using a `UIImagePickerController` to display the camera view so that the user can take a photo using the app. However, I would like to edit the `UIImagePickerController's` Camera View top bar - I'm referring to the bar which allows the user to toggle settings such as the flash and front facing camera.

Using the `UIImagePickerController` property `cameraOverlayView` I can access and modify the camera view. However, I was wondering if it was possible to access the top bar specifically, or find its dimensions. This is because if I had access to this, it would be easier to maintain my custom view objects which I will be adding (I do not have to guess where the top bar is located).

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: change front or rear and flash on/off are default options which came automatically when you present uiimagepickercontroller.

Comment: @Lion Yes - However, I am trying to add a custom timer button as well on the top bar.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this,

```
  self.pickerOverlayView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
UIButton *timerButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2) - 25, 10, 50, 30)];
[timerButton setTitle:@"Timer" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[timerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(timerButtonclick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.pickerOverlayView addSubview:timerButton];

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[picker setCameraOverlayView:self.pickerOverlayView];
```

Make custom overlayview, then create button and add to that overlayview and set that view as `cameraOverlayview` of your imagepickercontroller.

By above code you will get timer button in center of your top bar of imagepickercontroller.

`pickerOverlayView` is the property type of `uiview`. And `picker` is `UIImagePickerController` object.

`timerButtonclick` is method that you can handle to perform desired task.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I appreciate your help, but unfortunately this does not answer my question. I realise that you can simply add a overlayview like this, but the problem comes with the maintenance of this. This is because the top bar will change in width for each device, hence it will be hard to maintain for different screen sizes. Hence, I was wondering if there was any way to specifically access the top bar of the UIImagePickerController camera  or its attributes. Thanks